# Changes to the element's text breaks it's parent delegated event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic-content

I'm working on a drop down menu as part of a school project. I've gotten most everything to work properly but I ran into an issue with JQuery events that I couldn't quite find the answer to, whenever I click on my list item it sets the list name properly but after that none of the events work. I put the handlers on parent elements to see if that helped but still nothing.

Here's a quick look at the JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('nav ul').on('mouseenter', '.menu1', function(){
  $('.menu1 ul').removeClass("hidden");
});

$('nav ul').on('mouseleave', '.menu1', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.menu1 ul').addClass("hidden");
  }, 300);
});

$('nav ul').on('click', '.menu1 ul li', function(){
  $('.menu1').text($(this).text());
});


});
```

I have a code pen for the list as well.

https://codepen.io/JFarenci/pen/gvoQvq

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `$('.menu1').text($(this).text());`

After this line gets executed on choosing an option, the portion inside the `li` tag changes to this: `<li class="menu1">one</li>` (assuming you had chosen 'one'). The `ul` tag along with the dropdown menu is overwritten.

To fix this, have a separate space to display the selected option above the `li` tag.

HTML:

```
    <p id="selected"></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $('nav ul').on('click', '.menu1 ul li',function({
       $('#selected').text($(this).text());   
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah this makes the most sense, I had been so set on getting the css animations and jQuery to work right that I forgot about how that works in html. Whoops...

Comment: Hey @JacobFarenci, if this solved your problem do you mind accepting this answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. I removed your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and replaced it with `mouseover`.
2. On each `click` I added a `span` containing `$(this).text()`.  Note that it's preceded by a `remove()` to handle for prior clicks when the text was set.

See runnable snippet to test.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('nav ul').on('mouseover', '.menu1', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.menu1 ul').show();
    }, 300);
  });

  $('nav ul').on('click', '.menu1 ul li', function() {
    $('.menu1').find("#click").remove();
    $('.menu1').append('<span id="click">' + $(this).text() + '<span>');
  });


});
```

```css
nav {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav>ul>li:hover {
  background: #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.dropMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.dropMenu li {
  background: #666;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

ul.dropMenu li:hover {
  background: #606060;
}

ul.dropMenu li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  /*opacity: 0;*/
}

li:hover>ul.dropMenu {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

li:hover>ul.dropMenu li {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

li:hover>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-out;
  animation-name: fold-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0ms;
  animation-delay: 0ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:hover>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-out;
  animation-name: fold-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 60ms;
  animation-delay: 60ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:hover>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-out;
  animation-name: fold-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 120ms;
  animation-delay: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li:hover>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-out;
  animation-name: fold-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
  animation-delay: 180ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fold-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg);
    transform: rotateX(15deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes fold-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg);
    transform: rotateX(15deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
}

li>ul.dropMenu {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

li>ul.dropMenu li {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

li>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-in;
  animation-name: fold-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0ms;
  animation-delay: 0ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-in;
  animation-name: fold-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 60ms;
  animation-delay: 60ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-in;
  animation-name: fold-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 120ms;
  animation-delay: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

li>ul.dropMenu li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-name: fold-in;
  animation-name: fold-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 120ms;
  animation-duration: 120ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 180ms;
  animation-delay: 180ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fold-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
  }
}

@keyframes fold-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="menu1">
      <ul class="dropMenu hidden">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>fork</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```